# php blog style gallery

Tags: php

after a long search on google i found below php code for image gallery, but it produce jquery effect after cick on thumbnail, instead of jquery i want to go to other page that shows full respective image, like a wordpress blog does!

```
<?php
    # SETTINGS
    $max_width = 200;
    $max_height = 200;
    $per_page = 9;
    //$imagedir = 'gallery/';
    $page = $_GET['page'];

    $has_previous = false;
    $has_next = false;

    function getPictures() {
        global $page, $per_page, $has_previous, $has_next;
        if ( $handle = opendir(".") ) {
            $lightbox = rand();
            echo '<ul id="pictures">';

            $count = 0;
            $skip = $page * $per_page;

            if ( $skip != 0 )
                $has_previous = true;

            while ( $count < $skip && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' )
                    $count++;
                    }

            $count = 0;
            while ( $count < $per_page && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                    if ( ! is_dir('thumbs') ) {
                        mkdir('thumbs');
                    }
                    if ( ! file_exists('thumbs/'.$file) ) {
                        makeThumb( $file, $type );
                    }
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']">';

                    echo '<img src="thumbs/'.$file.'" alt="" />';

                    echo '<div class="fb">view</div></a></li>';


                    $count++;

                }

            }

            echo '</ul>';

            while ( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                    $has_next = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getPictureType($file) {
        $split = explode('.', $file); 
        $ext = $split[count($split) - 1];
        if ( preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext) ) {
            return 'jpg';
        } else if ( preg_match('/png/i', $ext) ) {
            return 'png';
        } else if ( preg_match('/gif/i', $ext) ) {
            return 'gif';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    function makeThumb( $file, $type ) {
        global $max_width, $max_height;
        if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
        }
        if ( ($oldW = imagesx($src)) < ($oldH = imagesy($src)) ) {
            $newW = 220;
            $newH = $max_height;
        } else {
            $newW = $max_width;
            $newH = 200;
        }
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor($newW, $newH);
        imagecopyresampled($new, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newW, $newH, $oldW, $oldH);
        if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
            imagejpeg($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
        } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
            imagepng($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
        } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
            imagegif($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
        }
        imagedestroy($new);
        imagedestroy($src);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `rel` attribute from the anchor element in the `while` loop outputting the images. This would prevent the Lightbox script from binding events to this link, so when users click it, they will simply be redirected to the image specified in the `href` attribute.

In other words, instead of

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']">';
```

use

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'">';
```

Comment: but how i pass same image to other php page?

Comment: Not sure I understand your meaning. Clicking the link would automatically redirect the user to the image, as you asked in the original post.

Comment: yes you are right, but on clicking thumbnail it shows orignal image instead of orignal i want to display image in specific page like singlepost.php?
hope fully you got my question?